# Maintain Session after app Update in React Native

Tags: ios, authentication, react-native

I have currently working on react native ios app and for testing purpose i have submitted app on test flight mode in ios. 
I have created session management with help of AsyncStorage this feature helpful still app will not updated,but after app updated AsyncStorage  will dis-troy.

My question is that how to maintain app session storage after app will updated.

If any one have idea please answer this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can save login data directly in database (for example you can use something like Realm).

However pay attention on how you use AsyncStorage especially on Android (you probably don't want to have a "clear data" backup on Google, see [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13542)).